# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed when call API

Tags: angular2-routing

I have same API, when call API in angular 2 I get this error:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

My Webconfig:

```
<system.webServer>


    <rewrite>
      <!--This directive was not converted because it is not supported by IIS: RewriteBase /.-->
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index\.html" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
     <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
```

If remove rules tag  in web config my API is worked, but when refresh angular page I get this error:

> The resource cannot be found.

Comment: this link 'http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Exception-HTTP-Error-4050-Method-Not-Allowed-The-page-you-are-looking-for-cannot-be-displayed-because-an-invalid-method-(HTTP-verb)-is-being-used

Comment: why are you using `rewrite` ?

Comment: because when refresh angular page  page i get this error
he resource cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your browser of choice, if might be worth getting acquainted with the usual F12 developer tools that usually come with them for a bit of clientside visibility.

It's useful to verify that your client isn't trying to do something that you weren't expecting, you can see the verbs, content types and the urls that might assist you tracking it down.

Also you're using url rewrites in your config, so the server could be adjusting your requests after they're received, possibly in a way you weren't expecting - Suspect I'll need a bit more information on the relative urls that are failing to provide more advice.

An example is that in Chrome, you can check the Network tab.

[image: chrome developer tools - network tab]

Comment: before add this code  call api is successd


  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>


if remove this code my api is word but when refresh page  i get  this error
The resource cannot be found.